# Son nom est ou son nom c'est

Tags: grammaire

I just wanted to know why and what we would use:

> Son nom c'est Einstein.

or

> Son nom est Einstein.

It's used for a dog.

Comment: Pour insister : « Son nom, c'est Einstein, il … » ; pour le nommer « Son nom est Einstein. »

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use both of them while speaking, I'm not shocked (as a native French).

But "son nom est" sounds better, and you should use this one while writing (and if you're writing formal language) .